# Why do online players of Carcassonne always win, is there a strategy?

Tags: ios, carcassonne

At home and with friends I'm a pretty good player of the boardgame and app of Carcassone, but every time when I try an online opponent I keep losing, because it seems they alway get the right tiles.

Is there a strateqy behind it by knowing the algorithm in which order the app will present the next tile? For example, with the last 10-15 cards they always manage to get 2 or 3 extra people in the fields by getting just the right tiles. In the regular boardgame this rarely happens.

Does the iPad version of the game give out tiles deterministically?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just confirmation bias?

Answer (score 7):

If the online players are playing well, then yes, it is possible to know roughly what cards are coming near the end of the game.

There are a fixed number of cards of each different type in the game:

[image]

Near the end of the game, as long as you've been keeping track of what's come up already, you will know exactly what cards remain and can plan accordingly.

This is no different from the regular board game version though.